# How to achieve UIButton / UILabel 'padding' in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton, uilabel, padding

I've got various views in my iPhone application that require padding e.g a custom UIButton with text aligned left, and a UILabel with a background color.

This may be a really stupid question, but how can I apply 'padding' to move the text off the left hand edge?

I've tired using bounds etc without any success.

I know I could create a wrapper view for my `UILabel` with a background color, but it seems like overkill.

Many thanks.

Comment: Marco Arment tweeted a dead-simple `UILabel` subclass that adds `UIEdgeInsets`-style padding in label drawing: it’s on gist.github as [IPInsetLabel](https://gist.github.com/2596057).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok the simplest solution I've found so far is:

```
self.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 
[self sizeToFit]; 
CGRect frame = self.frame;
frame.size.width += 20; //l + r padding 
self.frame = frame;
```

Not exactly what I wanted, but it works.

Comment: I failed to tweak this solution to work for alignment left. It's a really old answer, I guess it might not work in iOS 6. Hope someone could provide update.

Comment: Works great, but from iOS 6.0 you have to use NSTextAlignmentCenter, UITextAlignmentCenter is deprecated.

Answer (score 119):

I am using **auto layout**. Solution that worked for me was setting `UIButton`'s **`contentEdgeInsets`**.

###ObjC

```
button.configuration.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 30.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f);
```

###Swift

```
button.configuration.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 30.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 30.0)
```

Comment: Note for future readers, `contentEdgeInsets` seems deprecated with iOS 15. Now that property is ignored when [UIButtonConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration) in use. And its related method [.setDefaultContentInsets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration/3869632-setdefaultcontentinsets?changes=_4) is being presented with `Beta Software` notice.

Answer (score 22):

To set padding in `UIButton` text you need to use `UIButton`'s `contentEdgeInsets` property.

In Storyboard, to set content inset do following steps:

1. Select the view controller, then select the `UIButton`
2. Go to Utilities Panel (Command + Option + 0) and select Attributes Inspector (Command + Option + 4)
3. Now select **Content** in **Edge** and set **Inset** as per your
   requirement (see screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Now its in Size inspector

Comment: Now its the Button -> Content Insets under the Size Inspector

Comment: XCode 9 onwards UIButton -> Size Inspector -> `Content Insets`  ==> as shown in this image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49959281

Answer (score 9):

To add padding to UILabel the most flexible approach is to subclass UILabel and add an edgeInsets property.  You then set the desired insets and the label will be drawn accordingly.

**OSLabel.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OSLabel : UILabel

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets;

@end
```

**OSLabel.m**

```
#import "OSLabel.h"

@implementation OSLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        self.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, self.edgeInsets)];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 6):

On **Xcode 9**, the insets are now located in the **Size Inspector** instead of the Attributes Inspector:

[image: Xcode 9 Size Inspector - Button insets]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sublass of UILabel that has customizable padding using an edgeInset property:

**PaddedLabel.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface PaddedLabel : UILabel
@property UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets;
@end
```

**PaddedLabel.m**

```
#import "PaddedLabel.h"
@implementation PaddedLabel
-(void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, self.edgeInsets)];
}
-(CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    CGSize contentSize = [super intrinsicContentSize];
    UIEdgeInsets insets = self.edgeInsets;
    contentSize.height += insets.top + insets.bottom;
    contentSize.width += insets.left + insets.right;
    return contentSize;
}
@end
```

(This is a simplification of Brody's answer which also works with autolayout.)

Answer (score 2):

**CGRectInset** is your friend. You can set negative 'insets' to create padding:

```
[self sizeToFit];
CGRect rect = self.frame;
rect = CGRectInset( rect, -6.f, -5.f); // h inset, v inset
self.frame = rect;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to achieve a similar thing, that is 'pad' a `UILabel`. I've been trying to implement the solution that Toby posted above, but can't seem to find where this needs to go.
The UILabel I'm working with is aligned left - is that what's causing the issue?

I've tried using this in `viewDidLoad`, and even in a subclass of UILabel in the method:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
     limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a custom class that extends UIButton and overriding this:

```
- (CGRect)titleRectForContentRect:(CGRect)contentRect
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(contentRect, UIEdgeInsetsMake(topPadding, rightPadding, bottomPadding, leftPadding));
}
```

In the case of UILabel just override:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds 
     limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can activate `NSLayoutConstraint`s between `button` and `button.titleLabel`

```swift
let button = UIButton()
button.setTitle("Retake", for: .normal)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(button)
guard let label = button.titleLabel else { return }
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    
    // setup constraints for button relative to view
    
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
    label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerXAnchor)
])
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're just looking for a horizontal padding on one line, then this may be enough (it was for me):

```
NSString* padding = @"  "; // 2 spaces
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", padding, name, padding];
```