# adjust .sizetofit() with button width swift

Tags: swift

I have a button and a couple labels. I like how the size to fit works, but, its a little to close to the edges on the left and right side. How do  I fix this? I want to add a couple extra pixels to the left and right side.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to achieve UIButton / UILabel 'padding' in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052731/how-to-achieve-uibutton-uilabel-padding-in-iphone-app)

Comment: close, what about doing this with a label?